# Saying "Goodbye!" to a deceased person

Tags: word-request

To say "Goodbye!" to a deceased person on their funeral, would you also use "Vale!"? Wouldn't that be oxymoronic, since "Vale!" means "Be healthy!"?

So, how would one say their last "goodbye" in Latin?

Comment: If you can swallow the idea that you're addressing a dead person as though they can hear you, you might reconsider how logical what you say has to be :) But anyway, many languages have no better word for "goodbye" than well-wishing (or even for "hello"; some use the same words whether someone is coming or going). In English we have "may God be with you" (by Shakespeare's time "God be w'ye", a.k.a. "goodbye")  and "may you fare well" (a.k.a. "farewell"). We can also give our "salutations", from Latin *salus* "healthy". All sound fine at a funeral despite being logically out of place.

Comment: @LukeSawczak sometimes we're busy swallowing something else while addressing a (recently) dead person, and need something to say - some kind of goodby or farewell - almost anything - to justify it :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a famous poetic example, take Catullus, *Carmina* 101:

> Multas per gentes et multa per aequora vectus
>    advenio has miseras, frater, ad inferias,
> ut te postremo donarem munere mortis
>    et mutam nequiquam alloquerer cinerem,
> quandoquidem fortuna mihi tete abstulit ipsum,
>    heu miser indigne frater adempte mihi.
> nunc tamen interea haec, prisco quae more parentum
>    tradita sunt tristi munere ad inferias,
> accipe fraterno multum manantia fletu,
>    atque in perpetuum, frater, **ave atque vale**!

Saying *vale* works.
It doesn't wish good physical health but being strong and sound on the other side or on the journey to it.